# Reorder - Blog categories in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: blog

Is it possible to reorder(by default it sorts by asc) the blog categories in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

The categories is just a simple web part.  Go to the categories list and create your desired sort order.  Then edit the web part properties of the categories web part and set it to use the newly created view.